# Trying to pass a base64url encoded token in the url but it keeps failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, webapi

so I am trying to pass a base64url encoded JWT token via the url to a web api. I have tried using both Postman and Fiddler and I get the same result. Before anything is even executed on the server I get a 400 Bad Request error. Anyone know what could be up?

**My request**

```
https://localhost:XXXX/api/MXlKaGJHY8lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y8NJNklrcFhWM8o5LmV5SjBiMnRsYmlJNkltMFVhMVJhWnpaV1REaEJLekIwVTFkWWJMMnMUVE81VFVkaloMTkpNMFpCTWpCRk1XVlRiVnBNY2tGcVNWTXJiMmd6YUVSYVMscFRMVVl2MG8wMWNrUTRlVTVaVFMoWVNrUk1PVFMTMERkclMWUkJkbEJuUFMwaUxDSnVMbVlpT2pFMk1UYMROamt3TXpRc8ltVjRjM8k2TVRMeE56MMNNall6TkN3aWFXRjBJam94TmpFM89EWTVNRE8wTENKcGMMTWlPaUppWVdOaGNIMnpMbXAMMENJc8ltRjFaM8k2SW1KaFkyRndjSE11WVhCcEluMC5TV8EtRE5GYy16WXJtSHFMT3lieG1IN1lIMVd1RmFFTTB3MWtNVnJjSWtr/people
```

**My routing in webapiconfig file**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "somename",
                routeTemplate: "api/{token}/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

The XXXX in the localhost will be a number, I have added the XXXX naturally for security issues. If I try the same url but with a cut down version of the token then it at least gets executed and starts the rest of the job, however my calls fall over as its not a valid base64url encoded jwt. If the error was with the code I'd set up then at least I could find out where and why, but this does not even hit anything. Its almost like I have hit the limit in the URL. I even tried add the following in the webconfig but made no difference.

```
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="10000"
```

Can anyone help me to see what the issue is. By the way I am using ASP.NET with C#, if that helps.

Comment: "I have added the XXXX naturally for security issues" - the port your server is running on within your machine, which I'd expect to be behind a firewall, is really not sensitive information.

Comment: Jon Skeet - I am sure you are correct, however can never be to careful. I have also played around with the encoded text so no once can try and decode it. Again probably not needed but you never know who wants to do some nefarious actions.

Comment: even if it doesn't really answer the question: is it really necessary to pass the token through the URL?  Usually I would prefer the Authorization header for this.

Comment: I suppose not, in theory I could create my custom token header, but I am trying to do something which is relatively straight forward for our api users. I know in the pas using Google api requires you to add a key parameter. Looking back I think that was a query string parameter. I have tested querystring and this works so not sure why this doesn't with my routing. Also I have found that I get the error once I reach 295 characters.